# Is method toLocal8bit in QString class safe?

Tags: c++, qt, encoding

I have a file with UTF-8 without BOM encoding. I have to load data from that file ( only one line ) and hold it in QString variable. Next I have to convert this data from QString variable to other QString, but with UTF-8 encoding. So I have:

```
QFile file(R"(C:\Users\tom\Desktop\myFile.txt)");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QTextStream textStream(file.readAll());
textStream.setCodec(QTextCodec::codecForLocale());
QString stringVar = textStream.readLine();

...

QTextStream textStream2(stringVar.toLocal8Bit(), QIODevice::ReadOnly);
textStream2.setCodec(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
QString stringVar2 = textStream2.readLine();
```

And it works. But in `toLocal8bit()` docs there is a text:

```
Returns the local 8-bit representation of the string as a QByteArray. The returned byte 
array is undefined if the string contains characters not supported by the local 8-bit encoding.
```

In windows-1250 ( my locale codec ) encoding we have 251 characters ( 251 / 256 ). I tried situation, when in file I have a 2 bytes character which contain a byte doesn't appear in windows-1250 ( 0x81 ) and qDebug show 'Ă\u0081', when I show stringVar and next the proper character when I show stringVar2. Everything is ok. So using toLocal8bit() is safe in my situation?

EDIT:
I can't load data from file using UTF-8 - I have to load it using locale codec.

Comment: "*I have a file with UTF-8 without BOM encoding ... I can't load data from file using UTF-8 - I have to load it using locale codec*" - If the file is UTF-8, why wouldn't you want to load it as UTF-8? That makes no sense. You need to explain your use-case better.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Because I have 2 possibilities of encoding file - UTF 8 without BOM and windows 1250. When I load data to file as UTF-8 and file will have windows-1250, I lost data.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't have that problem if you were using UTF-8 with a BOM instead. But without that, you will have to analyze the bytes of the file to check if the encoding is UTF-8 or Windows-1250. You already have the bytes in memory from `file.readAll()`, not that hard to analyze them. Otherwise, you could simply try loading the file in one encoding, and if it fails to decode properly then retry with the other encoding.

Comment: If you use the wrong encoding with the `QTextStream` then it will not decode the input bytes correctly and the resulting `QString` will be corrupted before you can do anything with it. Using `toLocal8Bit()` after the fact will not fix that, or help you restore the original data, it is already gone.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for answer. Yeah, but it is still a problem: for example letter sequence "ćąą" in polish. When I save it using windows-1250 encoding and load bytes to app I will see "0xE6 0xB1 0xB1" and... in UTF-8 it is a correct character. So here we have 2 good answers and I would like to have a checkBox, which will change a encoding on screen.

Comment: "*I will see "0xE6 0xB1 0xB1" and... in UTF-8 it is a correct character*" - and this is why quessing an 8bit locale in a Unicode world is bad. If you have to guess an encoding, you are going to guess it wrong sometimes. Can't you phase out Windows-1250 from your program and just require UTF-8 only? You can convert existing Windows-1250 files to UTF-8 externally, such as with ICONV or similar tool. In any case, the byte sequence `E6 B1 B1` in UTF-8 decodes to Unicode U+6C71, which doesn't exist in Windows-1250, so it wouldn't be hard to validate if the resulting `QString` were decoded properly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau And here we have the big problem - I can't check if Unicode U+6C71 exists in windows-1250. Of course I can open wikipedia - section 1250 and check it, but I can't do that using QT. I tried something like that: 
    QByteArray ba;
    ba.resize(3);
    ba[0]=0xE6;
    ba[1]=0xB1;
    ba[2]=0xB1;
    QTextCodec *cod = QTextCodec::codecForLocale();
    QTextStream ttt(ba);
    ttt.setCodec(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
    QString zzz = ttt.readLine();
    qInfo()<<cod->canEncode(zzz);  And it return true, so... exists.

Comment: `canEncode()` is broken, see [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/93921/unexpected-result-from-qtextcodec-canencode-qstring/7) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36914716/65863). So, either don't use Qt to validate the result (validate it manually, or with another Unicode libray), or at least try using `cod->fromUnicode(zzz)` and see if it replaces any characters with `'?'` that weren't already `'?'` to begin with